# How can I use a bookmarklet to get an innerText from an external domain iframe? (x-origin errors)

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, cross-origin-resource-policy

I'm trying to use a bookmarlet to get a value from an iframe, which is loaded from another domain. I'm getting x-origin errors, but I don't need to communicate "between" the frames, I just need to read data from the iframe, like I would from the parent.

I do not have access to modify either the parent or child frame. I cannot load the child iframe alone either.

I recreated a super simplified version of the structure I'm working with.

**Parent page**
*url1.com/parent.html*

```html
<body>
  <h1>Parent Title</h1>
  <iframe src="url2.com/child.html" id="xoFrame"></iframe>
</body>
```

**Child iframe**
*url2.com/child.html*

```html
<body>
  <h1>Child Iframe Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus congue est vitae mauris pulvinar hendrerit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
  <a class="button" href="#">Child Frame Button</a>
  <footer>&copy; Footer Text 2048</footer>
</body>
```

I found a "solution" that would work for me as I would only be running it on my computer. It involves running Chrome with a few flags. However, it didn't change anything. Running Chrome 109.

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process --user-data-dir="C://chrome-dev"
```

For the purpose of this test, I'm trying to get the `innerText` of `a.button` inside the iframe. I created four different bookmarlets to illustrate my point.

---

**Bookmarklet 1**

```js
console.log('TEST 1. TRYING TO ACCESS PARENT > H1:');
console.log(document.querySelector('h1').innerText);
```

**Result 1**

```
TEST 1. TRYING TO ACCESS PARENT > H1:
Parent Title
```

---

**Bookmarklet 2**

```js
console.log('TEST 2. TRYING TO ACCESS CHILD IFRAME > A.BUTTON DIRECTLY');
console.log(document.querySelector('a.button').innerText);
```

**Result 2**

```http
TEST 2. TRYING TO ACCESS CHILD IFRAME > A.BUTTON DIRECTLY
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerText')
    at <anonymous>:1:132
    at <anonymous>:1:145
```

---

**Bookmarklet 3**

```js
console.log('TEST 3. TRYING TO ACCESS IFRAME > CONTENTWINDOW');
console.log(document.getElementById('xoFrame').contentWindow);
```

**Result 3**

```
TEST 3. TRYING TO ACCESS IFRAME > CONTENTWINDOW
global {window: global, self: global, location: {…}, closed: false, frames: global, …}
```

---

**Bookmarklet 4**

```js
console.log('TEST 4. TRYING TO ACCESS IFRAME > CONTENTWINDOW > DOCUMENT');
console.log(document.getElementById('xoFrame').contentWindow.document);
```

**Result 4**

```
TEST 4. TRYING TO ACCESS IFRAME > CONTENTWINDOW > DOCUMENT
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "url1.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at <anonymous>:1:147
    at <anonymous>:1:159
```

---

All I need is a solution that would return `Child Frame Button` in this scenario.

Comment: @Yogi Forgot to mention in the original post that I'm open to solutions that would only work locally by disabling the Chrome same origin policy. I found a "solution" that involves running Chrome with a few flags. However, it didn't change anything. Running Chrome 109.

`chrome.exe --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process --user-data-dir="C://chrome-dev"`

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Bookmarklets run in the context of the top level frame.

They are subject to the same cross-origin security restrictions as any other JS running in that frame.

Comment: Forgot to mention in the original post that I'm open to solutions that would only work locally by disabling the Chrome same origin policy. I found a "solution" that involves running Chrome with a few flags. However, it didn't change anything. Running Chrome 109.

`chrome.exe --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process --user-data-dir="C://chrome-dev"`

Answer (score 0):

After posting this, I went and looked back at starting Chrome with web security disabled. This works with Chrome 109.

**Make sure ALL instances of Chrome are closed before running it.**

```
chrome.exe --disable-site-isolation-trials --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process --user-data-dir="C:\chrome-dev"
```

---

**Bookmarklet 5**

```js
console.log('TEST 5. TRYING TO ACCESS IFRAME > CONTENTWINDOW > DOCUMENT > A.BUTTON');
const iframeDoc = document.getElementById('xoFrame').contentWindow.document;
console.log(iframeDoc.querySelector('a.button').innerText);
```

---

**Result 5**

```
TEST 5. TRYING TO ACCESS IFRAME > CONTENTWINDOW > DOCUMENT > A.BUTTON
Child Frame Button
```

---